# Error with Symfony and PHP 7.2.5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, php-7.2

I'm trying to use symfony without success. It is working in local, but I get an error in production.
Can someone help ? thank you :)

**the error :**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv::populate() must be an instance of Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\void, none returned in /home/admin/web/clair-net-precis.tk/public_html/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:95\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/admin/web/clair-net-precis.tk/public_html/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(57): Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->populate(Array)\n#1 /home/admin/web/clair-net-precis.tk/public_html/public/index.php(15): Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->load('/home/admin/web...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /home/admin/web/clair-net-precis.tk/public_html/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 95
```

**php -v server :**

```
PHP 7.2.5-1+0~20180505045740.21+stretch~1.gbpca2fa6 (cli) (built: May  5 2018 04:57:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.5-1+0~20180505045740.21+stretch~1.gbpca2fa6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**php -v dev :**

```
PHP 7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2018 04:59:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Make sure your httpd also runs the same version (eg. create a simple php file just calling `phpinfo()` and verify the version).

Comment: Same error listed on the Symfony github at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25469

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, down to the line number (95),

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv::populate() must be an instance of Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\void ...
```

As per @Glen Pinheiro , I disabled the php7.0 module (after ensuring  my other packages were updated) and then enabled the php7.2 module. After a quick restart of Apache, things were in order.

In other words:

```
sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.2
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform following operations to resolve the above issue,

```
sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.2
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```